# Code to define biological and technical replicate samples (brain twister)

Tags: r, duplicates

In my expression dataset I have various kinds or replicates, biological and technical. A biological replicate I consider if the same person was sampled at different dates. A technical replicate I consider if a sample was taken from the same person at the same date and measured either at the same or different dates.

I tried to define this by code but unfortunately im hitting a wall with trying to define technical and biological replicates. 
Below is my code that defines replicates and first replicates (=index case) but for the rest it would be amazing if someone could help me. Its kind of a brain twister so kudos to anyone solving this!

Thanks a lot!

Sebastian

```
df<- data.frame(
  sample = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
  individual = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "f", "d", "e"),
  date_collected = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 1.1),
  date_processed = c(2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.1 ))

#differentiate biological and technical replicates
df$has_replicate <- FALSE #all that have a replicate
df$is_first_of_replicates <- FALSE #primary sample
df$is_technical_replicate_same_run <- FALSE #same sample, same date processed
df$is_technical_replicate_different_run <- FALSE #same sample,     different date processed
df$is_biological_replicate_same_run <- FALSE #same individual, different date collected, same day proc
df$is_biological_replicate_different_run <- FALSE #same individual, diff date col, dif day proc


#check all samples that have replicates = same individual (including first one)
replicates_index <- which(df$individual %in%         df$individual[which(duplicated(df$individual))])
#mark
df[replicates_index, ]$has_replicate <- TRUE

#define first samples (by checking which ones are not the first ones)
replicates_not_first_index <- duplicated(df$individual)
df[replicates_index, ]$sample #all that have replicates incl first
df[replicates_not_first_index, ]$sample #all replicates that are not first
#find replicates that are first = present in rep but not in not first
firstsIDs_ <- setdiff(df[replicates_index, ]$sample,     df[replicates_not_first_index, ]$sample)
#get index
firsts_index <- which(df$sample %in% firstsIDs_)
#mark
df[firsts_index, ]$is_first_of_replicates <- TRUE
```

## expected output

```
df$is_technical_replicate_same_run # TRUE if is replicate & date.collected same & date processed is the same
df$is_technical_replicate_different_run # TRUE if is replicate & date.collected same & date processed is different
df$is_biological_replicate_same_run # TRUE if is replicate & date collected is different & date processed is the same
df$is_biological_replicate_different_run # TRUE if is replicate & date collected is different & date processed is different
```

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question.

Comment: .. (i.e. what `df` from your example is supposed to look like).

Comment: Sorry, I thought its explained by the part in the expected results section. Please tell me if its not clear. What I want is that the defined columns (eg df$is_technical_replicate_same_run) should contain TRUE if the defined condition is met (eg TRUE if is replicate & date.collected same & date processed is the same)